# how to change the output result to zero of a sql script?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

This is my script

```
   SELECT a.iPriority_num AS [TransNUM],b.sItem_nm as [Item],a.mSellingPrice_amt AS [aMT],
        SUM(c.mCash_amt) AS [CASH]
        ,SUM(c.mCCard_amt) AS [CC]
        ,SUM(c.mEPS_amt) AS [CEPS]
        ,SUM(c.mGCheque_amt) AS [GC]
        ,SUM(c.mCheque_amt) AS [OTHERS]
    FROM Table1 a
    LEFT JOIN Table2 b
    ON a.sPlu_cd=b.sPlu_cd
    LEFT JOIN Table3 c
    ON  a.iPriority_num=c.iPriority_num AND
    a.iBranch_num=c.iBranch_num 
    AND b.iCompany_typ=c.iCompany_typ
   WHERE a.IAPPLY_DT BETWEEN 20130701 AND 20130731
    AND a.iBranch_num=14
    AND a.iStatus_typ=1
    AND a.sSellUnit_CD='PC'
    AND a.IPRIORITY_NUM=118271
   GROUP BY 
   a.iPriority_num,b.sItem_nm,a.mSellingPrice_amt
```

The Result is

```
   TransNUM Item  Price     Cash      CC      EPS    GC      others        
   118271   Item1 204.0000  392.0000 .0000  .0000   .0000   .0000
   118271   Item2 188.0000  392.0000 .0000  .0000   .0000   .0000
```

I want to make the value of 2nd row(392) to 0 only. Im using sql 2000 here.

Comment: I am curious. why do you want the query output to be zero instead of say modifying it on your frontentd

Comment: Any particular RDBMS?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I believe it's MSSQL, since there are square brackets in the query

Answer (score 0):

This query will give the result you want:

```
SELECT a.iPriority_num AS [TransNUM],b.sItem_nm as [Item],a.mSellingPrice_amt AS [aMT],
      [CASH] = CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER () OVER 
                  (ORDER BY a.iPriority_num,b.sItem_nm,a.mSellingPrice_amt) = 2 
               THEN 0 ELSE SUM(c.mCash_amt) END
      ,SUM(c.mCCard_amt) AS [CC]
      ,SUM(c.mEPS_amt) AS [CEPS]
      ,SUM(c.mGCheque_amt) AS [GC]
      ,SUM(c.mCheque_amt) AS [OTHERS]
 FROM Table1 a
 LEFT JOIN Table2 b
 ON a.sPlu_cd=b.sPlu_cd
 LEFT JOIN Table3 c
 ON  a.iPriority_num=c.iPriority_num AND
 a.iBranch_num=c.iBranch_num 
 AND b.iCompany_typ=c.iCompany_typ
WHERE a.IAPPLY_DT BETWEEN 20130701 AND 20130731
 AND a.iBranch_num=14
 AND a.iStatus_typ=1
 AND a.sSellUnit_CD='PC'
 AND a.IPRIORITY_NUM=118271
GROUP BY 
a.iPriority_num,b.sItem_nm,a.mSellingPrice_amt
```

But I'd better to do this on client-side rather than server-side

Comment: I got error! 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name., Im using mssql2000 here.

Comment: Oh, I missed that! This solution works for MSSQL 2005 and higher